# The word "spoken" as an adjective

Tags: verbs, adjectives

In the phrase below...

> How to improve your spoken English

is the word "spoken" an adjective? Can the word "spoken" usually take the form of an adjective? I see this construction very often, but when I looked it up in the Cambridge dictionary I got that it is just a verb.

Comment: Your cited text isn't a question - it's a [Nominal Relative Clause](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/clauses/nomrel.htm), which could be incorporated into a question as, for example, *"**Do you know** how to improve your spoken English?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this *spoken* is an adjective.

In my opinion, Macmillan Dictionary is friendlier to learners; for example, you can look up the word ***[spoken](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/spoken)*** on their website, and you will find that it's clearly defined as *adjective*, with the definition: "spoken language is things that people say, not things that they write".

For more information related to using *-ed* and *-ing* verb forms as adjectives, I'd like to recommend reading [Participial Adjectives @ The Internet Grammar of English](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/particip.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Almost any past participle can be used as an adjective. The idea of the Latin term participle is that a participle is a verb form that can be used as a verb form or an adjective. "Participle means having the character of two  word classes.
Examples:
a beaten dog, a frozen lake, a broken window, a burst tyre/tire (AmE).
A good survey as to participles is given in
grammar-monster.com - What are participles?

http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participles.htm