# Why is "ed/d" added to “motivate” in “10 Ways To Keep Yourself Motivated Learning English”?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, participles

I know this is a very, very simple question. I went googling by myself, but I'm unsure what the proper keyword for this question would be. I only know "ed/d" is suffix for regular verbs like “added” or “matched”.

I often see this “ed/d” suffix in articles I read, but I only remember these other examples:

- I'm confused.
- I'm motivated.

Comment: is it not something to do with the physical *state* you're in (i.e. state of confusion. not state of confuse, state of motivation, not state of motivate)

Comment: I recommend reading the posthttp://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33174/the-word-spoken-as-an-adjective

Comment: Thanks for the link @rogermue , I will try to search more detail about "convert verb to adjective" keyword,Thanks.

Comment: This is no conversion from one word class to another. It is the double nature of participles that they are verb forms that can also be used as adjectives. Your key word should be "participles".

Comment: hmm okay, I will read about adjective tutorial and how to apply it in sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, what you're looking at is known as a *participle*, and is used when you want to turn a verb into an adjective.

> There are two types of participles:
>
> - The Past Participle (usually ending -ed, -d, -t, -en, or -n)
> - The Present Participle (ending -ing)

Here, *motivated* is the past participle of the verb *motivate*, and is being used as an adjective to describe *yourself*.

[Click here to read a more detailed explanation of past and present participles.](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm)

Comment: "Motivated" is an adjective for "Yourself" and in this case "motivated" is used to describing more about yourself ( noun )? Am i right ?

Comment: @mockie Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

**'-ed' adjectives**

> Adjectives that end in -ed are used to describe how people feel:

- He was `surprised` to find that he had been upgraded to first class.
- I was `confused` by the findings of the report.
- She felt `tired` after working hard all day.

**'-ing' adjectives**

> Adjectives that end in -ing are used to describe things and
>   situations. Compare these example sentences to the ones above:

- Being upgraded to first class is `surprising`.
- The findings of this report are `confusing`.
- Working hard all day is `tiring`.'

I got this answer from :
http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/ed-and-ing-adjectives-describing-feelings-and-things/